# How to resolve Leaflet TypeError: L.control.selectLayers is not a function

Tags: leaflet

I wish to make a dropdown list to replace the default tool for layer selection.
Using this example included in from the GIT repository, and adjust for jsfiddle, I get the following error:

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#77:31'>77:31</a> TypeError: L.control.selectLayers is not a function"
```

using L.control.layers works fine, however, not selectLayers.

```
//var control = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps)
var control = L.control.selectLayers(baseMaps, overlayMaps)
control.addTo(map);
```

The appropriate javascript files all seem to be in place, so.. what is missing here?
[Fiddle link:](https://jsfiddle.net/0mkychrL/)

Comment: Have you tried using the dev console in the browser to see what `L.control.selectLayers` is? You could set a breakpoint at your error and then see if the function object was null, undefined, reassigned, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the wrong link of the libraries.

You have to use the [raw](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vogdb/SelectLayersControl/master/src/SelectLayers.js) link instead of the [Github](https://github.com/vogdb/SelectLayersControl/blob/master/src/SelectLayers.js) link

[image]