# Python folium - failed to load Leaflet plugins

Tags: javascript, python, folium

I would like to load Leaflet plugins to Python folium.

So far I used the BigImage plugin, which is here:

https://github.com/pasichnykvasyl/Leaflet.BigImage

My code looks as follows:

```
map.get_root().header.add_child(folium.CssLink("css/Leaflet.BigImage.min.css"))

map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.JavascriptLink("css/Leaflet.BigImage.min.css"))

png_js = '''

L.control.bigImage({position: 'topright'}).addTo{map};

'''.replace("{map}", mapJsVar)
map.get_root().script.add_child(Element(png_js))
```

but I am getting an error:

**TypeError: L.control.bigImage is not a function**

I don't understand this error, because due to this thread:

[How to resolve Leaflet TypeError: L.control.selectLayers is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770480/how-to-resolve-leaflet-typeerror-l-control-selectlayers-is-not-a-function)

I should have picked up the RAW code, which I certainly did.

Where is the problem then?

Comment: Add a complete URL for your links. `folium.CssLink("https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/src/Leaflet.BigImage.css")`

Comment: It looks like it works. However, why should I pull an original link?  I replicated it to my own directory? Where is the difference though?

Comment: For a local file you can also prepend the path with ‘file://‘ to make it into a url.